# Is this a sufficient condition for the integral to be greater than $m$?

Tags: integration, functions

It is given that $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is positive continuous function.

If it is positive then it means that it never goes below the $x-$ axis. I want to find a sufficient condition such that we have
$$
\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx \gt m 
$$
($m$ is a positive number). I thought that this problem wants us to find a necessary condition such that the area under $f$ in the interval [0,1] is greater than the area of rectangle of length 1 and height $m$.

I thought that as the function is always positive, so if it ever goes above $m$ for any $x$, that is
$$
\exists x ~~~~~ f(x) \gt m
$$
Then the area will be more than the rectangle. I want to know if my thinking is true?

Comment: No, tjhat does not work.  With $f(x)=x$ we have $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \frac 12$ but $f(1)=1$.  (Note:  I am guessing you meant "sufficient" as in the header).

Comment: In the title you write "sufficient", in the text you write "necessary". Which one do you need?

Comment: No. If it only exceeds $m$ on a small subinterval and stays much smaller elsewhere the total area may well be less than $m$. In fact, it can be made as small as one wishes by making that subinterval very short.

Comment: So are you asking if $\exists x\in[0,1] | f(x)>m \Rightarrow \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx \gt m$ is correct?

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso Yes

Comment: @Gibbs I corrected the body with “sufficient”.

Comment: @Knight then the answer is no, it's not correct. I'll work on a solution, but intuitively you can see that $f$ can take very small values in $[0,1]$ except in a small interval, and that leads to $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx \gt m$ being as small as you want even existing that $f(x)>m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That there is a point $x$ in $[0,1]$ such that $f(x)>m$ is not sufficient to get the conclusion wanted (see the counterexample by lulu in the comments). In general $f>m$ in $[0,1]$ is a sufficient condition. You may want to find a weaker assumption though.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please talk about some weaker assumptions?

Comment: What I meant is that there are cases where $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx > m$ but $f$ is not greater than $m$ for all $x$ in $[0,1]$. Such an $f$ is easy to imagine (e.g. $f$ can take value $m/2$ for all $x \in [0,1/2)$ and then increase rapidly above $m$ making the integral on $[0,1]$ greater than $m$). So one can play with this behavior and find a class of functions not necessarily greater than $m$ everywhere but satisfying the condition on the integral anyway.

Comment: Okay, that means for any general $f$ the only wise thing to conclude is that $f \gt m$, right?

Comment: I would say that is the most obvious thing to conclude, but it is certainly not necessary.